# High performance parsing of string in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I am writing a program to parse a log line string in Java. A sample syslog is given below:

```
<34>1 2003-10-11T22:14:15.003Z mymachine.example.com su - ID47 - BOM'su root' failed for lonvick on /dev/pts/8
```

Apart form this there will be logs from other sources.

I was using Grok parser for this purpose. But all the available libraries utilizes 100% CPU when the number of logs are higher (around 20000 logs per second). I use threads to achieve this rates.

Is there any other way for parsing these logs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you like to get out of this string? Can you give us an abstract pattern of what the logs will always look like? E.g. if they always start the same and you don't need that part for parsing you can just discard it

Comment: If there is plenty work to do, changing library wont change that (im assuming that usage is not caused by bad impl)

Comment: @Lino There is no specific patterns. The logs can be from any sources, from syslog to firewall to router etc. I was trying to parse them all with Grok

Comment: @Antoniossss so what should I do?